# Doing a modification in all numbers in text string

Tags: php, regex, explode

I have a lot of text strings, like that

'from 12.34 to 56.78'

OR

'12.34 to 56.78'

OR

'12.34'

I want to modify these number in all these strings

```
<?php
$array = explode(' ',$string);
foreach ($array as $value) {
    if(is_numeric($value))
        $newarray[] = round($value); // or other functions
    else
        $newarray[] = $value;
}
$newstring = implode(' ',$newarray);
```

Is this a best way for doing any modifications?

Comment: what should be the expected result of such *modifictions* ?

Comment: I think it's a pretty efficient solution if you're sure the only seperator is a space.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest text string like the inputted string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As from your comments, you might have a look at `preg_replace_callback()`.
Consider the following code which rounds all your numbers pretty easily:

```
<?php

$strings = array('from 12.34 to 56.78', '12.34 to 56.78', '12.34');
$values = array();

$regex = '~\b\d[\d.]+\b~';
foreach ($strings as $string) {
    $string = preg_replace_callback($regex,
        function($match) {
            // or anything else
            return round($match[0]);
        },
        $string);
    $values[] = $string;
}

print_r($values);
# [0] => from 12 to 57
# [1] => 12 to 57
# [2] => 12

?>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, But I want to input a string that has few numbers, and return the same string with the new numbers after modify these numbers, I think that your code will extract the numbers from the all  strings

Comment: @Mostafa: You could use `preg_replace_callback()` then, do you want an example?

Comment: Thanks for giving me the name of good function, I'll search about it now